# Identify bee in photo (found in Utah, USA)

Tags: entomology, species-identification

A friend took this photo of a bee in his back yard in central Utah (© Jon Mott, CC-BY 3.0). I have no formal training in systematics or entomology, so to me everything looks like the bees' poster child *Apis mellifera*. Can someone with a bit more experience confirm or refute this?

[image: honey drinker]

Comment: Maybe You should contact a local apiary and ask them about common bees in your are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this looks like *Apis mellifera*, which is also one of the most common bees you'll run into. If you have other pictures, you could check the identification tips at [the bugguide page for the species](http://bugguide.net/node/view/3080#id).

As a side note, in general to really **confirm** an identification a specialist would need to see a collected specimen (that is, a live or pinned bee) as the distinctive characters (things like size, wing veins, or in this case, long hairs on the eye) may not be visible in photographs.